# I get an error when adding "[]" to my application

Tags: angular, frontend

So I'm currently following a tutorial to make a task manager, and I get an error when I put `[]` in the code as following [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKD64.png)

```
export class TaskViewComponent implements OnInit {
  lists: any[];
  tasks: any[];

  constructor(private taskService: TaskService,private route:ActivatedRoute){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe(
      (parms: Params)=>{
        console.log(parms);
        this.taskService.getTask(params.listId).Subscribe((tasks: any[])=>{
          this.tasks = tasks;
        })
      }
    )

    this.taskService.getLists().subscribe((lists: any[])=>{
      this.lists = lists;
    })

  }

}
```

I have already set some of the "strict" restrictions to false.

If I remove the `[]` it doesn't give me an error, but the front end part of the code doesn't work, so I think I have to include this, but it doesn't allow me

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please share your code as snippet and what is the error? Thanks.

Comment: It's only a typescipt type it won't change how the code is interpreted...

Comment: What is the return type of `taskService.getLists()` and `taskService.getTask()` ?! I guess the return type of them is not array ! Make sure it's of type `Observable<any[]>`